# Django edit Form doesn't save

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm a Django beginner and i have a little problem. I made a form for create the model `FantaSquadra`, and this works. Then I made a form to edit the model and when I press the submit button it doesn't do anything.
Can someone help me?

urls.py:

```
 path('add/fantasquadra/', views.addFantaSquadra, name='creazione_fanta'),
 path('edit/fantasquadra/<int:fantasquadra_id>/', views.editFantaSquadra, name='edit_fanta'),
```

views.py:

```
def addFantaSquadra(request):
elenco_fantasquadre = FantaSquadra.objects.all()
if request.method == "POST":
    form = NewFantaSquadraForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        fanta_item=form.save(commit=False)
        fanta_item.save()
else:
    form = NewFantaSquadraForm()
return render(request, 'sondaggio/fantasquadre.html', {'form': form})

def editFantaSquadra(request, fantasquadra_id):
item = get_object_or_404(FantaSquadra, pk=fantasquadra_id)
form = NewFantaSquadraForm(request.POST or None, instance=item)
elenco_fantasquadre = FantaSquadra.objects.all()
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
return render(request, 'sondaggio/fantasquadre.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```
class NewFantaSquadraForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = FantaSquadra
    fields = ['nome_fantasquadra','proprietario']
```

fantasquadre.html

```
<html>
    <h1>Scrivi il nome della tua fantasquadra</h1>
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit"><a href="/sondaggio/">Submit</a></button>
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a link inside your button, for some reason. The link is taking priority over the button submission, so the data is never actually posted to the view.

Remove that `<a>` element.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But now how can i tell to django to redirect me in a specific page after i click the button?

Comment: You should return a redirect after `form.save()`.